# Questions about scala.tools/scala.tools.asm

Tags: scala

I am trying to use asm recently and just noticed that there is package for asm in scala already. Just want to know more about this.

1. purpose of package scala.tools and whether it is stable
2. any tutorial documents for scala.tools.asm package? how many differences between scala asm and original asm.
3. where can I find api for scala.tools.asm

My background: have some experience in java/scala. Not familiar with bytecode.

Thanks, 
W_vv

Comment: `scala.tools` contains implementation of the Scala compiler. It officially does not have any public, maintained API.